# Unable to fetch list from angular website using beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse nptel website ([url](https://nptel.ac.in/courses)) to fetch all courses listed on it.

[image]
Each course correspond to `app-courses-card` tag. The DOM looks like this:
[image]

I am unable to get hold of these tags with beautiful soup. I tried following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_text_from_webpage(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        for li in soup.select("app-course-card"):
            print(li.get_text())

    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

url = "https://nptel.ac.in/courses"
webpage_text = extract_text_from_webpage(url)
```

The print statement never executed since the list was always empty as no `app-courses-card` is captured by `soup.select()`.

I felt that angular data is taking up some time to get fetched. So I tried with selenium+beautiful soup by adding some delay. Still the webpage returned no list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (without opening a browser window)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def extract_text_from_angular_webpage(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text

angular_url = url = "https://nptel.ac.in/courses"
webpage_text = extract_text_from_angular_webpage(angular_url)

if webpage_text:
    print(webpage_text)

driver.quit()
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The data you see is loaded from external URL. You can use `requests` module to get the data and put it to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://nptel.ac.in/assets/course.json"

# names of institutions are found under this URL:
# https://nptel.ac.in/assets/institute.json

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()["data"])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
          id                                          title noc_url version content_type  discipline_id  institute_id                             professor tag_id is_public  current_run self_paced
0  101101087                   NOC:Lighter than Air Systems    None    None        Video            101             1                   Prof. Rajkumar Pant   None      None            1       None
1  101104065  NOC:Introduction to Ancient Indian Technology    None    None        Video            101             3                       Dr. D.P. Mishra   None      None            1       None
2  101104066      NOC:Introduction to Experiments in Flight    None    None        Video            101             3  Dr. A.K. Ghosh, Prof. Mahendra Verma   None      None            1       None
3  101104069                            NOC:Aircraft Design    None    None        Video            101             3                        Dr. A.K. Ghosh   None      None            1       None
4  101104086       NOC:Computational Science in Engineering    None    None        Video            101             3                       Prof. Ashoke De   None      None            1       None
```

Comment: Also friend of loading structured data - You can use `pandas` directly in this case `pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json('https://nptel.ac.in/assets/course.json')['data'])` but main issue here is that not all of the information is in this single source, you also have to load the other two JSON sources to map the name of institute and discipline.

Answer (score 1):

`implicitly_wait` doesn't wait for 10 seconds, it just sets up wait amount for methods that uses implicit wait.

Your site is rendered async, so `app-course-card` is rendered, but it's content hasn't been rendered yet, so you get empty results.

I suggest to add some wait for text content to be rendered at least for one element.

For example, each item has text Enroll Now, so you can wait for at least one element to has this content (or define some nicer solution).

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
def extract_text_from_angular_webpage(url):
    driver.get(url)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Enroll Now"]')))
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
    for li in soup.select("app-course-card"):
        print(li.get_text())

angular_url = "https://nptel.ac.in/courses"
webpage_text = extract_text_from_angular_webpage(angular_url)

driver.quit()
```